# Cannot access resources bundle

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, bundle, nsbundle

I have a project with several targets:

- MyLib - static library
- Resources - resources bundle
- App - example application

Now, what I'm trying to do is to access resources from Resources inside MyLib. I've added Resources in **Target Dependencies** and in **Copy Bundle Resources** in both MyLib and App. In Resources, I've added all the files I will need to **Copy Bundle Resources**.

However, I cannot access the Resources bundle, neither in My Lib, nor in App. `[NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier]` returns nil. In MyLib, when I list all bundles with `[NSBundle allFrameworks]` or `[NSBundle allBundles]`, I can see the App bundle, but not Resouces bundle. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find the answer:

Apparently, `bundleWithIdentifier` does not load a bundle. Documentation seems to be a little vague on this:

> This method creates and returns a new NSBundle object if there is no existing bundle associated with identifier. Otherwise, the existing instance is returned.

One might expect that you can just load a bundle with it, which is not the case. You need to load the bundle explicitly with `bundleWithPath`, like so:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath], @"Resources.bundle"]];
```

That fixed it for me.